# how to include a new file into a patch

Tags: diff, patch

I try to make a patch as introduced [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/163/how-to-create-patch-file-using-patch-and-diff/).
Say I have two directories `pp1(modified version)` and `pp0(clean version)`, I make a patch file `pp0.patch` with the `diff` command:

```
 diff -crB pp0 pp1 > pp0.patch
```

The problem is if there is a file only in pp1, it won't be included into the patch. How to work around it?

**UPDATE**:
 I firstly change into the directory of pp0 and test whether the patch will succeed

```
  patch --dry-run -p1 -i /path-to-pp0.patch
```

Though I've added `--new-file` to the `diff` command, those only in `pp1` are not listed in the result

**UPDATE**:
I've accidentally patched the wrong file so

```
  diff -crb --new-file pp1 pp0 > pp0.patch
```

or

```
  diff -crNb pp1 pp0 > pp0.patch
```

will do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `--new-file` switch. Taken from [diff man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff):

```
 --new-file
          In directory comparison, if a file is found in only  one  direc-
          tory, treat it as present but empty in the other directory.
```

Try this:

```
diff -crB --new-file pp0 pp1 > pp0.patch
```

Comment: I don't know whether I've patched it correctly but the new file is not included

Comment: my apology, that works

Answer (score 3):

The immediate answer: `diff -N`, as [explained by pootzko](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37287/how-to-include-a-new-file-into-a-patch/37295#37295). You'll find that a lot of patches out there are created by `diff -urN`.

What can make your life better: start using a version control tool. If you don't know any, start with one of the three main [distributed revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) systems, [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29), [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial). Check in the clean version, work, check in your work as many times as you like, and ask your version control system for a diff between the clean version and your work.

Comment: thx, wish I could have one in real life and reverted to the past when making a mistake :)